# How can I make the items on ActionBar to be one on the left, one in the center and one on the right?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using `actionbarsherlock` to do it.
Example of what I want in the actionbar: 
[LOGIN]     [COMPANY LOGO]     [FILTER]

Example of what I get in the actionbar: 
     
      [LOGIN]  [COMPANY LOGO]  [FILTER]

I have created the login button, company logo and filter button (in the form of drawables) in the res/menu's `activity_main.xml`. However, those buttons on the actionbar are unable to shift fully to the left, even though I have removed the default application logo and set those to `false`:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
```

here are my codes in the menu's `activity_main.xml`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/login"
      android:icon="@drawable/login_btn"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/logo"
      android:icon="@drawable/logo_btn"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/filter"
      android:icon="@drawable/filter_btn"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should create custom view for that. For example (`layout/ab_custom.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/center" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your Activity's `onCreate` call this method:

```
private void showActionBar() {
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.ab_custom, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
}
```

To take control on your items use this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            //left button, do something
            return true;
        case R.id.btn2:
            //center button
            return true;
        case R.id.btn3:
            // right button
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** revised my answer. It's better to use `RelativeLayout as parent`.

Comment: In fact, the correct way to inflate is: `getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.ab_custom);`

Comment: How to leave **back** title?

Comment: Adding Buttons to a custom View like this doesn't wire them up to the ActionBar's option selection mechanism, so onOptionsItemSelected won't get called when the buttons are clicked. I've tried manually adding an onClickListener, but that never gets called either. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I could net get this to work fully using `onOptionsItemSelected`, so I did it using settings clicklisteners manually.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the items inside a RelativeLayout. Then use:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft
android:layout_alignParentCenter
android:layout_alignParentRight
```

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Sabre's answer and address snadandpepper's comments. In order to set onClickListeners to the button, you can do the following.

```
private void showActionBar() {
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.my_toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.btn1).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "showActionBar: btn1 clicked");
        });
}
'''
```